# Polynomials, integrals convergence

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Let $P_n(x)= \frac{x^n(bx -a)^n}{n!}, \ \ \ a,b,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Prove that $\int_0 ^{\pi}P_n(x) \sin xdx \rightarrow 0 \ \ \ \ $ and $ \ \ \ \ \int_0 ^r P_n(x)e^xdx \rightarrow 0$ $ \ \ \ \ \ \ (n \rightarrow \infty)$.

How does that imply that $\pi$ and $e^r, \ \ r\in \mathbb{Q}$ are irrational?

Could you help me with that?